# change content of a cell using row id

Tags: jquery, html

I am generating a table. The table having a check box columns to select rows.Each row have a column named status .     While clicking  a button on the page i want to update the status column to 'working' using jquery.

I get the selected row id using jquery in button click event using jquery

```
  $('#BttnChangeStatus').click(function () {
         var selectedCalls = [];
         $('#result_table :checked').each(function () {
             selectedCalls.push($(this).val()); //the row id and value of check box are same
            //need to update status to working'.. how can i do this

         });
```

How can i update status column??

Comment: What do you mean by "update the status column to 'working'"?

Comment: there is a column having header named 'status' in my table. I want to change the content of that column of each selected row while clicking the button

Comment: OK, now what do you mean by "column named status"? How do you identify the relevant cell in each row? A `class`?

Comment: I dont know. Can i gave id on table cells too???.  if i know table row id and column id,can i update that column?

Comment: You can. A `class` would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if status column doesn't have any identifier then

```
    $('#result_table :checked').parents('tr').children('td:eq(x)').text("working...");
```

where x is the number of status column in your table.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply .its working fine.. if i know the id of the cell, then how can i use the above code?

Comment: if you know the id of status cell then you can just use $("#"+id).text("working...");
this code asumed that status cell is not different from other cells. if status column cells have a class then you can use $('#result_table :checked').parents('tr').children('td.status').text("working...");

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $('#rowid').find('#columnid').text('working') or
 $(this).find('#columnid').text('working')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing anything about your markup..

```
$('#result_table :checked').each(function () {
  selectedCalls.push($(this).val()); //the row id and value of check box are same
  $("#" + $(this).val()).find("td:eq(3)").text("Working...");
});
```

Where `$("#" + $(this).val())` will give you the current row. and `td:eq(3)` will get your the td cell at index 3.  From there you should simply be able to change the text.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/F7BWD/).**